# From Search results page: how to determin URL of previous page where SmallSearchInputBox was used?

Tags: search

This might be a bad idea, but that's no important right now. I'm determined to find an answer to the following:

I'm looking to create a custom search results page (based on osssearchresults.aspx) that shows the refinements panel if the search was done from a particular part of my site.

To elaborate:
I have a SmallSearchInputBox in my master page, which is used for ALL pages in my publishing sitecollection. One site within that collection is our "support site", and documents there are being created using metadata. Marketing pages are not.

When someone enters a search term into the SmallSearchInputBox and submits it, I want to be able to determine where that submission was made (from a page within the support site or the marketing site?) and show the refinements page accordingly.

This could, potentially, be a simple C# issue, but I've tried the usual suspects (Request.UrlReferrer, Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"], etc.) with no luck. It seems that the page you see after a form submissions (in my case results.aspx) cannot use these methods.

Any ideas?

Cheers